# Google Cloud Run FastAPI Uvnicorn Docker Random Restart occuring

Tags: python, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have a(some) trading bot(s) that run 24/7 on Google Cloud Run developed in Python controlled through restAPI using FASTApi. My bots each have their own cloud run instance. They execute well most of the time,... I can get the stats I want to put on my front-end. However, at times I notice the WSGI app restarts on CLoudRun??? In doing so it stops my looped trading function. As most times it's not problematic, I have had it happen mid-trade which is unsettling. I'll post a few snippets to hopefully provide context into a answer. Thank you.

```
FROM python:3.10
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD exec python3 -m uvicorn bot_handler:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

@app.get('/start',dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())])
def start():
    thread=Thread(target=bot_instance.start)
    thread.daemon=True
    thread.start()
    return {"status":200}

Info
2022-10-14 21:16:22.402 MSTGET200670 B3 mspython-requests/
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:26.421 MSTINFO: Shutting down
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:26.523 MSTINFO: Waiting for application shutdown.
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:26.523 MSTINFO: Application shutdown complete.
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:26.523 MSTINFO: Finished server process [1]
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:41.955 MSTINFO: Started server process [1]
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:41.955 MSTINFO: Waiting for application startup.
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:41.956 MSTINFO: Application startup complete.
Default
2022-10-14 21:42:41.956 MSTINFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Default
2022-10-14 22:58:52.745 MSTVALIDATING CONFIG FILE...
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run instances are ephemeral. Cloud Run Services are intended to process requests, not run background tasks. If an instance isn't actively processing a request, Cloud Run may shut it down and (and spin up new instances if either minScale is set or it gets more requests) if it needs to update the host. If you need an instance that doesn't restart unless you tell it to, use a VM.